# Boundary Condition - "second order Neumann Condition"

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Is there any "second order Neumann condition"? i.e.
I mean $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \vec{n}^2} = g$

I think $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \vec{n}^2}$ can be defined as $\triangledown( \triangledown f) \cdot \vec{n} $, right?

If we don't usually do this, may I know why? What difficulties will occur in this boundary condition?

Comment: You can certainly have second derivative boundary conditions, but this would really only apply to a PDE which is at least third order in space.

Comment: If the 2nd order pde is on a rectangle, will it be fine to use 2nd derivatives boundary condition?